# Running Zenoss from VirtualBox in OSX - Login Fails

Tags: mac-osx, virtualbox, zenoss

I downloaded the OSX version of Zenoss to trial it. Unpacking the .zip results in virtual hard drive files (.vdmk etc).

I spun it up in a VirtualBox machine, and after a bunch of stuff loaded I'm presented with a screen...

```
To access the Zenoss Management Console, please browse to: http://10.0.2.15:8080
localhost login:
```

When I enter login: admin pass: zenoss (as described in their [FAQ](http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-2446#Whatisthedefaultloginfortheimage)) I get told the login is incorrect.

Am I missing something? Browsing to the IP in my host OS(X) times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at some very old documentation. The 4.2.x series install PDF says to use user:root password: zenoss

Comment: Thanks:) That seems to get me some sort of command line root access. I suppose I need to be browsing to http://10.0.2.15:8080, however this does nothing in my host OS. How can I access the GUI?

Comment: I have tried in Bridge and NAT mode with port forwarding. Accessing the IP from the host always times out.

Comment: I got it  to work using the port forward instructions in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537751/virtualbox-port-forward-from-guest-to-host). Thanks again!